# how to use promise function in javascript functional function like forEach reduce?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, promise, async-await

I am using promise function like this:

```
// WORK
let res = {approveList: [], rejectList: [], errorId: rv.errorId, errorDesc: rv.errorDesc};
for (let i = 0; i < rv.copyDetailList.length; i ++) {
    const item = rv.copyDetailList[i];
    const v = await convertCommonInfo(item);
    if (!item.errorId) {
        res.approveList.push(v);
    } else {
        res.rejectList.push(merge(v, {errorId: item.errorId, errorDesc: item.errorMsg}));
    }
}
```

This works well, but I want to try to use some functional function, I find that I have to use `map` then reduce

```
// WORK, But with two traversal
const dataList = await promise.all(rv.copyDetailList.map((item) => convertCommonInfo(item)));

const res = dataList.reduce((obj, v, i) => {
    const item = rv.copyDetailList[i];
    if (!item.errorId) {
        obj.approveList.push(v);
    } else {
        obj.rejectList.push(merge(v, {errorId: item.errorId, errorDesc: item.errorMsg}));
    }

    return obj;
}, {approveList: [], rejectList: [], errorId: rv.errorId, errorDesc: rv.errorDesc});
```

I find that `forEach` function can not work:

```
// NOT WORK, not wait async function
rv.copyDetailList.forEach(async function(item) {
    const v = await convertCommonInfo(item);
    if (!item.errorId) {
        res.approveList.push(v);
    } else {
        res.rejectList.push(merge(v, {errorId: item.errorId, errorDesc: item.errorMsg}));
    }
});
```

This doesn't work, it just return init value. **In fact this puzzle me, sine I `await` the function, why not work?**

Even I want to use `reduce` function:

```
// NOT WORK, Typescirpt can not compile
rv.copyDetailList.reduce(async function(prev, item) {
    const v = await convertCommonInfo(item);
    if (!item.errorId) {
        prev.approveList.push(v);
    } else {
        prev.rejectList.push(merge(v, {errorId: item.errorId, errorDesc: item.errorMsg}));
    }
}, res);
```

But since I am using `Typescript`, I got error like this:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(prev: { approveList: any[]; rejectList: any[]; errorId: string; errorDesc: string; }, item: Resp...' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: { approveList: any[]; rejectList: any[]; errorId: string; errorDesc: string; }, c...'.
Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '{ approveList: any[]; rejectList: any[]; errorId: string; errorDesc: string; }'.
Property 'approveList' is missing in type 'Promise<void>'.
```

So I want to know two things:

1. **Why `forEach` await can not work?**
2. **Can I use promise function in reduce?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572) (it's the same for `reduce`)

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly approaching this backwards. Generally, you want to use `compose` to combine all the transformations and pass that composed function to the `.then` handler of a promise:

```
// assumes curried times and add functions
let tranformData = _.compose(square, times(2), add(3));

let foo = fetchNumberAsync() // returns a promise of 3
  .then(transformData)
  .catch(err => doSomethingWithError(err));

foo.then(console.log); // prints 144 to the console ((3 + 3) * 2) ** 2
```

Compare to the alternatives:

```
// clear but wasteful
let foo = fetchNumberAsync()
  .then(n => n + 3)
  .then(n => n * 2)
  .then(n => n ** 2)
```

or

```
// performant but opaque
let foo = fetchNumberAsync().then(n => ((n + 3) * 2) ** 2)
```

Using `compose` (especially with `memoize`) is a good middle road.

Answer (score 1):

**Why forEach await can not work?**
You provide an async function to forEach, but inside the implementation of forEach function, it is not awaited. I guess the forEach is like that:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function (func) {
    for (let item of this) {
        func(item);    // Note here, there is no "await" in front of it 
    }
}
```

**Can I use promise function in reduce?**
No, you cannot same reason as above.

The alternative way via "co" to smooth your code is like the below:

```
let ret = await rv.copyDetailList.map(co(function * (item) {
    const v = yield convertCommonInfo(item);
    if (!item.errorId) {
        res.approveList.push(v);
    } else {
        res.rejectList.push(merge(v, {errorId: item.errorId, errorDesc: item.errorMsg}));
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your ultimate goal is to achieve a single traversal where each iteration runs concurrently, then there are various libraries available that provide an *"asynchronous each"* along the lines of what it sounds like you're looking for.

One such library is [async-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-parallel), which offers a **Parallel.each** iterator that works nicely with async/await.

Using this library your code could look like this...

```
let res = {approveList: [], rejectList: [], errorId: rv.errorId, errorDesc: rv.errorDesc};
await Parallel.each(rv.copyDetailList, async (item) => {
    var v = await convertCommonInfo(item);
    if (!item.errorId)
        res.approveList.push(v);
    else
        res.rejectList.push(merge(v, {errorId: item.errorId, errorDesc: item.errorMsg}));
});
```